# Android - Hide date field in datepickerdialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

How to hide/remove date field in datepickerdialog.
Actually my requirement is to use the native date picker dialog but it shows up with day, month, and year. But as per my requirement i need only month and year. So i want to hide or remove the day field from the view.

Any help will be much usefull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField(){

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(_activity, ExpiryDateSetListener,cyear,cmonth, cday);
    try{
    Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) { 
        if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
            datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
            Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
               if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                  datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                  Object dayPicker = new Object();
                  dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                  ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
            }
         }

      }
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
  return dpd;

}
```

Use the above code for hiding the day field in DatePickerDialog.

Refer this [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-hide-date-field-in.html)

Comment: This is a vile recommendation. The most reliable answer is to roll your own. Even if you want to play script-kiddie games like what is proposed here, don't use reflection -- get at the particular widgets via `getDatePicker()` and `findViewById()` and set their visibility that way. Both approaches make assumptions about internal implementations that may not be valid across Android OS releases or OEM firmware modifications, but at least the `findViewById()` approach will make fewer assumptions (and probably run faster).

Comment: mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

Comment: Awesome. But "mDayPicker" does not work. It should be "mDaySpinner".

Answer (score 13):

I don't recommend using Reflection to do this kind of thing.

There is a simpler and more pretty way to do so:

```
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Be aware that `.getDatePicker()` method from `DatePickerDialog` works on `API LEVEL >= 11`.

Comment: This will cause a null pointer exception on lollipop devices as they use a different date picker layout.

Comment: I'm also getting a Null Pointer Exception. I'm on Android 6.0.1

Comment: give me null view

Answer (score 6):

The source code to [`DatePicker`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java) and [`DatePickerDialog`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java) are available for you to clone, refactor into your own package, and modify to suit.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();// Initialize Calendar
```

dialog_date_picker.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp">
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Set"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" /></LinearLayout>
```

DialogMethod called on Click:

```
private void ExpiryDialog() {
    System.out.println("Inside Dialog Box");
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_date_picker);
    dialog.show();
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    date_time_set = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set);
    datePicker.init(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(0);
    ll2.getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    date_time_set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            dialog.dismiss();
            Integer month = datePicker.getMonth()+1;
            Integer year = datePicker.getYear();
            expMonth = (month.toString().length()   == 1 ? "0"+month.toString():month.toString());
            expYear = year.toString();
            etExpiryDate.setText(expMonth + "/" + expYear);
        }
    });
}
```

This code works and hides the day in a DatePicker, so I can show Expiry Date for Cards. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

```
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This works properly

Comment: Some more comments regarding what the code does would be helpful.

Comment: On Android 6.0.1, I get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        txtMonth.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
    }

}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

refer this link [Disable day selection on datepicker example](http://learnlinky.com/2016/12/disable-day-selection-android-datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I am a little too late but posting the edited answer provided by @ULHAS PATIL above that works in case someone needs the same thing!

```
private Calendar mCalendar;
mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();// Initialize Calendar
```

The xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/DarkGrey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/cancel"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/kontora_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/CoralRed"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

There should be index 0 to hide the date filled, in ll2.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE); and visibility set to View.GONE so the space for the date field is not occupied.

```
private void createDialogWithoutDateField() {
    Calendar mCalendar;
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Inside Dialog Box");
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.date_picker_layout);
    dialog.show();

    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    AppCompatButton okBtn = (AppCompatButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    AppCompatButton cancelBtn = (AppCompatButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    datePicker.init(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), null);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(0);
    ll2.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Integer month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
            Integer year = datePicker.getYear();
            String expYear = year.toString();
            tvMonthYear.setText(month+ " " + expYear);
        }
    });
 cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I don't think you need to go that deep unless you wanna customize it.. 
there is the :

```
mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

which is a very legitimate call to remove the calendar segment.

Comment: this comment is from 2013 :) maybe the public api changed and the call is deprecated ?