# Android only month and year picker in material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-datepicker

Im working on app that needs to input expiration date for credit card but andorid 5.0+ date time picker has only options for picking date with days.
Is there any library for that because I cant find any.
I also didnt find anything in material design guidelines regarding this.

Thx

Comment: Create 2 separate spinner one with months value and other one with at least 25 years values. You can add create array for month and year and inflate it to spinners.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year

Comment: None of these answers are suitable for material design app...

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no, I used old styled pickers. some material design library with this feature would be great...

Comment: @DominikMičuta i have same issue did you solved? please share

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan No, so far there is no official way and I also didnt find any library. We used old holo style dialog :(

Comment: In layout use standart DatePicker widget. In app logic you need to programatically with reflection remove DAY spinner e.g: like in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673842/android-hide-date-field-in-datepickerdialog or there are codes for removing day spinner in this question bellow.

Comment: i am using same but still it shows days

Answer (score 1):

Went ahead making a modified Date Picker called Simple Date picker ... have used the code similar to Date Picker just to show month and year. You can also provide your own theme to the SimpleDatePickerDialog.

see https://github.com/resengupta/Month-Year-Date-Picker

Comment: Yeah I found library like that but this is not in material design :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
        Field f[] = picker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : f) {
        if (field.getName().equals("mDayPicker")) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object dayPicker = new Object();
            dayPicker = field.get(picker);
            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
} 
catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
} 
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
} 
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
}
```

you can try this

```
DatePicker dpDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpDate);

// Initialize Date Picker
int year    = dpDate.getYear();
int month   = dpDate.getMonth();
int day     = dpDate.getDayOfMonth();
dpDate.init(year, month, day, this);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
        {
            int daySpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android");
            if (daySpinnerId != 0) 
            {
                View daySpinner = dpDate.findViewById(daySpinnerId);
                if (daySpinner != null) 
                {
                    daySpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
        {
            int monthSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android");
            if (monthSpinnerId != 0) 
            {
                View monthSpinner = dpDate.findViewById(monthSpinnerId);
                if (monthSpinner != null) 
                {
                    monthSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
        {
            int yearSpinnerId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android");
            if (yearSpinnerId != 0) 
            {
                View yearSpinner = dpDate.findViewById(yearSpinnerId);
                if (yearSpinner != null) 
                {
                    yearSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
```

for More Information

[Hide Day, Month, or Year from DatePicker in Android 5.0+ Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789907/hide-day-month-or-year-from-datepicker-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

Comment: This is solution for non material design date picker but not for material dialog official date picker.