# Android: Disabling/removing date from DatePicker dialog

Tags: android, android-number-picker

One of my features require the user to select a month and year, so the following is the method which will pop up the first attached image (d/m/y).

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                        //Check if selected month/year is in future of today. 
                                    }

                                }, year, month, day);

                        dp.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                        dp.setTitle("Set Monthly Overview");
                        dp.show();
```

[image]

However, i do **NOT** require the date. How can i disable user from selecting it, or **best of all**, to even not display the date option there?

What I wish to achieve is something like the following image in the best case scenario.

[image]

Comment: You can read the topic to custom your UI. http://sunilsuthar02.blogspot.in/2013/04/date-picker-like-iphone-in-android.html

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673842/android-hide-date-field-in-datepickerdialog

Answer (score 1):

Refer "[Android DatePicker change to only Month and Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year)" which will help you just display month and year in the datepicker. Hope this helps.